# Policy-Based Authorization with Angular and ASP.NET Core using Active Directory

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, active-directory, authorization, windows-authentication

I am developing an intranet application

**Backend**: .NET Core Web API-2
**Frontend**: Angular 4+

For the backend I used Windows Policy-Based Authorization and I am getting all the information for authorization from Active Directory. See below code:

My **Authorization Handler**

```cs
public class BranchUserHandler : AuthorizationHandler<BranchUserRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, BranchUserRequirement requirement)
        {
            string userCPNumber = context.User.Identity.Name;

            using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "CAPITECBANK"))
            {
                UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userCPNumber);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
                else
                {
                    string userCompany = user.GetCompany();
                    if (requirement.Company == userCompany)
                    {
                        string userDepartment = user.GetDepartment();
                        if (requirement.Department == user.GetDepartment())
                        {
                            string userDescription = user.GetDescription();
                            if (requirement.Description == userDescription)
                            {
                                string userTitle = user.GetTitle();
                                if (requirement.Title.Contains(userTitle))
                                {
                                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**Startup**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.ConfigureRepositoryContext(Configuration);
            services.configureRepositoryWrapper();
            services.AddCors(options => 
            {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:62000")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
            });
            services.ConfigureSwagger();
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
            });



            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("WorksInBranch", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new BranchUserRequirement("Information Technology", 
                    "Systems Development - Revenue & Products", "SYSTEM DEVELOPMENT", 
                    new List<string>{"Regional Manager", "Branch Manager", "Assistant Branch Manager",
                        "ATM Assistant", "Service Consultant", "Sales Consultant", "Junior Support Analyst: Card Processing Channels"})));

            });
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, BranchUserHandler>();
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(
                    options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    );
            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }
```

So, on the Angular frontend, I want the user to be authorized automatically if the user is currently logged in into their windows machine, i.e user must not be prompted to enter credentials if user is logged in on their windows machine.

Please note that I have two separate projects for the Web API and for the client-side.

I've looked around but found nothing that helps. Can anyone guide me on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for one of my projects.

The solution I gave to this problem was to use cookies and BehaviourSubject.

When the user logs in, we save the response data (username, user data, token) into cookies.

When the Angular app is loaded after closing,

we check if we have data stored in cookies,

if true, we check if the cookies are valid,

if true again, we allow the user to interact with the app

If there are no cookies or cookies are invalid we redirect him to login page.

On Logout we clear the cookies and set the user Subject to null

Example code

```js
  private user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(this.userCookies());
  public user$: Observable<User> = this.user.asObservable();


  userCookies(): User | null {
    const local = this.cookieService.get('userData');
    if (local) {
      return JSON.parse(local);
    }
    return null;
  }

  setUserCookie(user: User) {
    this.cookieService.set('userData', JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  login(payload) {
    return this.loginRequest(loginData).pipe(
      // login successful if there's a token in the response
      tap(data => {
        if (data && data.token) {
          this.setUserCookie(data);
          this.user.next(data);
          this.router.navigate([ '/' ]);
        } else if (data.error) {
          this.user.next(null);
        }
      }));
  }
```